# Visualization software for dynamics simulations

Tags: simulation

I am running a rigid body dynamics simulation for two objects - you can think of them as cars, planes, or any other 3D object. The output of the simulation is a state vector associated with each object, consisting of 3D position and rotation angles, and their time derivatives, parameterized by time.

After obtaining these results for each time step (results stored in a Numpy array or CSV file, etc), I would like to visualize (and animate) the trajectories of the two objects. The minimum visualization requirement would be a coordinate system triad for each object moving and rotating relative to each other, but it would also be nice to insert a glyph of the real object for a more "realistic" rendering.

The tools I am experienced with that may be of relevance are Paraview and Matplotlib, but I can't think of a way to represent a rotation (or glyph, for that matter) in either of those tools. The simplest option would be to generate a 3D line plot of the trajectories, but then you don't get information about the rotation angle. Might blender or other tool be useful here?

For example, I am aiming for something like this: [image]
Source: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/ToupieEuler.png